# Javascript: Export default with parentheses and colon

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, export, default

I am currently going through the code in: https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-data-simple-rest/src/index.ts

I noticed this in the export default section:

```
export default (
    apiUrl: string,
    httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson,
    countHeader: string = 'Content-Range'
): DataProvider => ({
     [code in here]
    })
```

Can someone please explain the parentheses and colon right after export default? Like, whats going on there? Ive never seen something like that. Are those argumenets to be used in Dataprovider? Any additional literature you can point me to to learn more?

I am not familiar with TypeScript, so a pure JS explanation is what I am looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: `I am not familiar with TypeScript,`   but that's what it is, in what way would you want a JS explanation here.   The only thing I can think your after is,  it's returning a function with said parameters and return of type DataProvider.

Comment: Not sure you read my answer below, hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard `export default` statement. `export default` will allow you to import JavaScript code from other files and name the variable with the following syntax. Let me give you a simple example:

```
// In file 'console.js'
export default () => console.log("Hello world");

// In file 'main.js'
import myVariableName from "./console.js";

myVariableName(); // Does: console.log("Hello world")
```

From a JavaScript standpoint, the code you present here just exports the following [anonymous function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-anonymous-functions/):

```
function (apiUrl, httpClient = fetchUtils.fetchJson, countHeader = 'Content-Range') { /* Function definition */ }
```

To fully answer your question, parenthesis are for function parameters, and colons are for type definition (TypeScript).

```
/** 
 * TypeScript function definition
 * This function takes one parameter 'a' of type string
 * Its return type is void
**/

const myLog = (a: string): void => {
  console.log(a);
}

// Doing this

export default myLog;

// Is equal to

export default (a: string): void => {
  console.log(a);
}
```

More information on the export statement are available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)